# Localization-friendly label for "Products ordered in last [ ] orders"

Tags: forms, labels, localization

We're working on a feature for our B2B web app that makes it easier for users to place orders with their (B2B) suppliers. An initial design has a dropdown box embedded in the label of one of the radio button options. I'd like to replace it with a regular label.

Here's the form:

```
Supplier:              [dropdown list of suppliers]

Items to Order:        (x) Products ordered in last [5  v] orders
                       ( ) Supplier's entire product catalog
                       ( ) Nothing (empty order)

Quantities To Order:   (x) Forecasted using order history
                       ( ) Matched to the last order for each product
                       ( ) Blank quantities
```

What's a good replacement for "`Products ordered in last [5  v] orders`" so we can switch from embedding a dropdown box inside text (bad for localization) with a regular label that can be prefixed to the dropdown box, e.g.

```
                       (x) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet: [5  v]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find this label very clear. What about embedding the word "orders" in the dropdown ?

[image]

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but wouldn't this have the same negative implications as OP's? I imagine he's having localization issues because when translated the word "orders" might not appear after the dropdown so he'd have to shift it around. With this example he wouldn't be able to shift it around because its embedded in his dropdown options.

Comment: Embedding in the dropdown was exactly the approach we decided on. @DasBeasto is correct that the dropdown approach may have localization issues too, but you can change the "Products ordered in last" to be a regular label (e.g. "Products Recently Ordered:") that doesn't rely on the dropdown completing a sentence, and then the localization issues are addressed. But it was putting the text in the dropdown that was the core of the improvement, so marking this as accepted answer. Thanks Tony!